# What exactly is a superview?

Tags: ios, uiview

If I have three UIViews, A, B, and C.  C is a subview of B.  B is a subview of A.

Is B the superview of C, or is A the superview of C?

Is this a correct statement?  A superview is any view that is NOT a subview?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't shown any effort. A google search for "Swift what is a SuperView" gave me the exact answer to your question.

Comment: I'm sitting her taking a video course on this, so I'm not exactly sure how I can prove effort, particularly given my searches on the question yielded nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, A is the superview of B, and B is the superview of C

```
viewA.addSubview(viewB)    
viewB.addSubview(viewC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this out using the `superview`property:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    var me = ""
    func printMe() {
        print("I am \(me)")
    }
    
    init(me: String) {
        self.me = me
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
let viewA = MyView(me: "A")
let viewB = MyView(me: "B")
let viewC = MyView(me: "C")

viewA.addSubview(viewB)
viewB.addSubview(viewC)

let superviewOfB = viewB.superview as! MyView
let superviewOfC = viewC.superview as! MyView

superviewOfB.printMe()
superviewOfC.printMe()
```

prints:

> I am A
>
> I am B